# How to use python vtk to get the stereo effect?

Tags: python, vtk, stereo-3d, stereoscopy

I got the vtk working for rendering 3D objects. Now I want to render it in stereo way. But cannot figure out how to do it I tried something like this

```
ren.ResetCamera()
window = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
#window.GetStereoCapableWindow()

#window.StereoCapableWindowOn()

window.AddRenderer(ren)
window.SetStereoRender(1)
```

But it doesn't work. Any body can give some idea?

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code will guarantee it will work

```
window = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
window.GetStereoCapableWindow()

window.StereoCapableWindowOn()

window.AddRenderer(ren)
window.SetStereoRender(1)
window.SetStereoTypeToInterlaced()
```